# ¿Hay alguna forma en CMD de copiar validando el tamaño de los archivos?

Tags: cmd

En un directorio y sus subdirectorios tengo más de 40.000 archivos. Mi pregunta es si en CMD o cualquier otro programa existe una forma de copiar y pegar verificando el tamaño de los archivos para dividir los archivos copiados en carpetas de 50 MB sin modificar o cortar por la mitad ningún archivo, de ser necesario que copie una menor cantidad de archivos en la carpeta. ¿Existe algo parecido?

Sería algo así:

```
xcopy "c:\folderoriginal" "c:\foldercopia" size 1024 MB
```

Comment: Hey Juan, quería solo asegurarme de que hayas visto este [repositorio](https://github.com/Ariel-MN/Copy_CMD_Assistant). Me gustaría saber si resuelve tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta

**No existe algo así.**

Si tienes archivos en subdirectorios estos podrían llamarse igual a otros archivos de directorios adyacentes así que tendrías que cambiar el nombre de los archivos para evitar conflictos en la copia. También será necesario prevenir los casos de archivos que superen los 50 MB permitiéndoles copiarse solos en una carpeta que pueda exceder el tamaño establecido priorizando así la integridad del archivo. Como puedes ver, esto ya empieza a tomar la forma de un programa echo a la medida para resolver un problema en concreto.

## Solución

Una forma de hacerlo es realizando un script CMD.

El siguiente script te permite acceder a todos los archivos y sus respectivos tamaños en un directorio y sus subdirectorios:

```
REM "Itera en los archivos de un directorio y sus subdirectorios"
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b /s %source%') do (
    
    set Archivo=%%f

    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%s in ('%%f') do (
        REM "Dimension del archivo"
        set Dimension=%%~zs
    )

)
```

Partiendo de aquí solo se trata de implementar la lógica que necesitas, pero como me gustó la idea ya la hice y aquí te lo dejo en un [repositorio](https://github.com/Ariel-MN/Copy_CMD_Assistant).